# IE8 Object doesn't support this property or method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

My code is working fine in firefox and chorme but it seems IE does not support forEach.

```
 var DataSet = JSON.parse(data.d);
                    var Table = DataSet.Table;
                    var Table1 = DataSet.Table1;

                    Table.forEach(function (field) {
                        var row = $("<tr><td>" + field.SrNo + "</td><td>" + field.BidderName + "</td><td>" + field.BidAmt + "</td>+<td>" + field.BidDate + "</td></tr>").hide(); ;

                        $('#gvDetails').prepend($(row));
                        $(row).fadeIn("slow");

                      //  $("#gvDetails").prepend("<tr><td>" + field.SrNo + "</td><td>" + field.BidderName + "</td><td>" + field.BidAmt + "</td>+<td>" + field.BidDate + "</td></tr>").fadeIn(1000);
                        LastRecord = field.SrNo;
                    });
```

Comment: Nop, it doesn't. Just include the [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim).

Comment: @elclanrs is there any alternative to .forEach? in my case? One which does not require refrencing additional files.

Answer (score 1):

IE 8 doesn't support `forEach`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679980%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I kinda figured that. But what is the alternative?

Comment: is there something stopping you from using a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result using the following:

```
var DataSet = JSON.parse(data.d);
var keys = Object.keys(Table);

for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
  var field = Table[keys[i]];
  var row = $("<tr><td>" + field.SrNo + "</td><td>" + field.BidderName + "</td><td>" + field.BidAmt + "</td>+<td>" + field.BidDate + "</td></tr>").hide();
  $('#gvDetails').prepend($(row));
  $(row).fadeIn("slow");

  LastRecord = field.SrNo;
}
```

You can retrieve the keys in the object using `Object.keys()` and then iterate the returned array of keys.